# Trying to run a code I wrote myself on my Terminal, the result: Permission denied

Tags: python

I wrote some code on my laptop and now I am trying to run this code. But it give me the output : `Permission denied`
Usually that should only happen if a different user would try to access it. But I am the user who wrote it and is trying to run it now. I feel like this will be an easy issue to resolve but any help would be nice! Thanks.

I wrote and saved the code in IDLE python. Once I finished I tried running it in my Terminal (I have the macOS Mojave Version 10.14.5) but then I ran into the issue.

```sh
Evandros-MBP:~ evandro$ ./Desktop/FunCodes/pwd.py
```

This is how I tried to call up the code. I don't see any issues here.

Comment: Hi, is the script marked executable? You can see in the output to `ls -l`.

Comment: Try `python pwd.py` or `chmod +x pwd.py`.

Comment: call it using `python`or `python3`, whatever is in your path. Or add a shebang to the script.

Comment: try executing it with python ./Destop/FunCodes/pwd.py

Comment: change the permissions of your folder and then try
 sudo python your_python_script.py

Comment: Does your script have a `#!` line at the start?

Comment: please provide more info about the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling the script with

```
./Desktop/FunCodes/pwd.py
```

try using

```
python ./Desktop/FunCodes/pwd.py
```

or also

```
python3 ./Desktop/FunCodes/pwd.py
```

if you want to execute it with python3 instead of python2.

### Explanation

When you write `./some-file` in the terminal (without writing `python` before the file path), the terminal executes it as a bash file (no matter if the file has a .sh extension or not). Of course, since your file is a python file, this will fail. But even before it fails, since your python file has no [permission to be executed](https://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4124/), permission will be denied and bash won't even start.

Answer (score 0):

On creation, the file only has read and write permissions. Add a shebang pointing to the Python interpreter on the script's first line, for example `#!/usr/bin/env python`. Also, your script is not marked as executable, in order to do that you need to use:

```
chmod +x pwd.py
```

Otherwise you will only be able to run it with Python, with

```
python pwd.py
```

Comment: `chmod +x` would work only if the file includes the correct shebang line